# TYPO3 / Extbase: Datamapper not working anymore with TYPO3 9.5.x

Tags: php, typo3, extbase, typo3-8.x, typo3-9.x

In older TYPO3 Versions like TYPO3 8.7.x, I used DataMapper to map the results from my querybuilder select result to an array of objects. That is working fine in TYPO3 8.7.x, but in TYPO3 9.5.x, I've got the error message "**Call to a member function buildDataMap() on null**".

```
//MyRepository.php

namespace Vendor\MyExtension\Domain\Repository;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\ConnectionPool;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Mapper\DataMapper;

/**
 * @param string $search
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function findBySearch($search)
{
    $querybuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable('tx_myextension_domain_model_produkt');
    $records = $querybuilder->select('tx_myextension_domain_model_produkt.*')
        ->from('tx_myextension_domain_model_produkt')
        ->orWhere(
            $querybuilder->expr()->like('titel', $querybuilder->createNamedParameter('%' . $search . '%')),
            $querybuilder->expr()->like('untertitel', $querybuilder->createNamedParameter('%' . $search . '%'))
        )
        ->orderBy('titel')
        ->execute()
        ->fetchAll();

    $dataMapper = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(DataMapper::class);
    return $dataMapper->map($this->objectType, $records);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some classes require other objects as dependencies. This is the case in TYPO3 if the properties are annotated with `@inject` or if there is a matching `injectPropertyName` method.

In that case, you should instantiate the class (DataMapper in this case) using the ObjectManager.

That usually looks like this:

```
$dataMapper = GeneralUtiity::makeInstance(ObjectManager::class)->get(DataMapper::class);
```

Comment: I can't see your class, but if your extending `YourClass extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Repository` then the ObjectManager is already available and you can use it with `$this->objectManager->get(DataMapper::class)`.

Comment: True, I forgot about that. Same if it's inside of an extbase controller.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `get` method of ObjectManager is marked as deprecated in TYPO3 version 10 I use `inject` annontation to get DataMapper instance

```
    /**
     * Datamaper
     *
     * @var DataMapper
     * @TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Annotation\Inject
     */
    protected $dataMapper;
```